# Setup ArcGIS 10.2.2 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, installation

I installed on Oracle VM VirtualBox two Windows Server 2008 R2.

•   One with ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 10.2.2

•   The second SQL Server 2012 in Mixed Mode

Because I'm not connected to a network, I use the Host-Only Ethernet Adapter Mode to let the host communicating with guests.
My questions are:
On what virtual machine should I have to install ArcSDE and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP1 Native Client.

If you could point me to a good tutorial, that would be great.

Comment: There is no need to install an application server, so the answer is neither.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer. I want to consume SQL Feature database for a project base on ArcGIS Server.

Comment: Use of Direct Connect obviates the need for an application server, so you don't have to install "ArcSDE" anywhere.  The ArcGIS Server/Desktop host always needs the correct database client, which is covered by the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002q00000038000000).